# Area bounded by parametric curve and $y=x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, parametric

I am familiar with how to find an area bounded by the parametric curve if I am given some $t \in <0,1>$ or such interval.

I can also find the area if I am told that the parametric curve is bounded by one (or combination) of those constant functions:

- $y  = A \quad A\in\mathbb{R} \quad\text{(e.g. }y=\sqrt{2}\text{)}$
- $x = B \quad B \in \mathbb{R} \quad\text{(e.g. }x=1\text{)}$

Problem is: what if I have to calculate an area bounded by some parametric curve and some other **non-constant** function like $y=x$?

Say, for example:

an area bounded by $\Bigg(x(t)=t^4-1,y(t) = t^4-t^2\Bigg)$ and $y=x$? How should I find the integral's boundaries/limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the time limits by setting $x(t) = y(t)$.
$$t^4-1 = t^4-t^2 \implies t = \pm 1.$$
So, the bounded area lies between $t=-1$ and $t=1$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to show me on the same example, but bounded by some other function like $y = x^2$ (or anything, really), so I can get a better grasp, please?

Comment: Oh, so bounded by $y = x^2$ I would need to solve something like this? $y(t) = (x(t))^2$

Comment: Let's say your third bound is $y = x^2$.  Then you would need to solve $(t^4-1)^2 = t^4-t^2$.